# Let A be a non empty subset of R .Let I(A) denotes set of interior points of A Then

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

Let $A$ be a nonempty subset of $\mathbb{R}$ .Let $A^\circ$ denotes set of interior points of $A$ Then $A^\circ$ can be

A. Empty

B. Singelton

C. A finite set containing more than 1 element

D. Countable but not finite

I think it is "D" but I am not sure.

Comment: Are we talking about the standard topology of $\mathbb{R}$?

Comment: @SujaanKunalan yes

Comment: Consider $\{7\}$- the interior of this set is empty.

Comment: maybe "at least one" of above cases is correct !

Comment: Also, consider the interior points of some interval, say $(1,2)$. Can you tell why this is uncountable?

Answer (score 1):

Are we working with $\mathbb R$ equipped with the usual metric? I'll assume so.

$A.$ It can be empty. Example: int$(\mathbb Q) = \phi$

$B.$ Can't be a singleton. If it were, then it's $\{a\}$ for some $a \in \mathbb R$, and this implies that there is a $\delta > 0$ for which $]-\delta + a, \delta + a[ \ \subset \{a\}$

$C.$ It can't be finite. Take $x \in$ int$(A)$, then $\exists$ $\delta > 0$ such that $]x - \delta, x + \delta[$ $\subset$ int$(A)$. But $]x - \delta, x + \delta[$ is infinite.

$D.$ It can't be countable due to what happened in $C.$ ($]x - \delta, x + \delta[$ is uncountable).

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**:

$\operatorname{int}(A)$ is an open set.

---

Some information apart from the hint:

In fact it can be defined as the "greatest" open set that is a subset of $A$. It is the union of all open sets contained in $A$ and as a union of open sets it is open itself.